# Golang: Не могу разобраться с кросс-компиляцией

Tags: linux, windows, golang, кросс-компиляция

История такая: написал приложение на Go с использованием PixelGl. Под линукс(а работаю я под ManjaroLinux) компилируется и запускается отлично. Но при попытке сделать ему go build под Windows64 происходит следующее:

`[123@123 dir]$ export GOARCH=amd64
[123@123 dir]$ export GOOS=windows
[123@123 dir]$ go build my_program_windows_amd64.go 
../../go/git/src/github.com/faiface/glhf/frame.go:7:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/123/go/git/src/github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl
../../go/git/src/github.com/faiface/pixel/pixelgl/input.go:6:2: no buildable Go source files in /home/123/go/git/src/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw`

И компиляция, естественно, не происходит

Я понимаю, что для того, чтобы скомпилировать эту штуку нужно собрать либы под винду

Но как это сделать - понять не могу. Не собирать же их вручную по одному, да и под линукс они собираются автоматически при компиляции проекта.

Поэтому прошу пояснить, если кто знает, как тут делается кросс-компиляция

На всякий случай прилагаю скриншоты $GOROOT и $GOPATH
[image: $GOROOT]

[image: $GOPATH]

---

@ainar-g попытался собрать стандартную либу, не вышло:

```
[123@123 registry]$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=".exe"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="windows"
GOPATH="/home/123/go/git"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/src/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0"
GCCGO="/usr/bin/gccgo"
CC="x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build747939891=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
[123@123 registry]$ go install std
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/bytes/bytes_amd64.go:7:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "bytes"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/compress/flate/huffman_code.go:9:2: non-standard import "math/bits" in standard package "compress/flate"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/crypto/sha1/sha1block_amd64.go:7:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "crypto/sha1"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/crypto/sha256/sha256block_amd64.go:7:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "crypto/sha256"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/crypto/sha512/sha512block_amd64.go:9:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "crypto/sha512"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/crypto/tls/cipher_suites.go:18:2: non-standard import "golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305" in standard package "crypto/tls"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/encoding/gob/decode.go:14:2: non-standard import "math/bits" in standard package "encoding/gob"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/go/importer/importer.go:12:2: non-standard import "go/internal/srcimporter" in standard package "go/importer"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/hash/crc32/crc32_amd64.go:12:2: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "hash/crc32"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/math/floor_asm.go:9:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "math"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/math/big/arith.go:11:8: non-standard import "math/bits" in standard package "math/big"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/mime/type_windows.go:8:2: non-standard import "internal/syscall/windows/registry" in standard package "mime"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/net/dial.go:10:2: non-standard import "internal/poll" in standard package "net"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:46:2: non-standard import "golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack" in standard package "net/http"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/os/file.go:41:2: non-standard import "internal/poll" in standard package "os"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/strings/strings_amd64.go:7:8: non-standard import "internal/cpu" in standard package "strings"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:8:2: non-standard import "internal/syscall/windows/sysdll" in standard package "syscall"
can't load package: /usr/local/src/go/src/time/zoneinfo_windows.go:9:2: non-standard import "internal/syscall/windows/registry" in standard package "time"
```

Comment: А кросс-компилятор си под Windows у вас установлен?

Comment: @Ainar-G это что такое? я знаю только обычный, стандартный gcc

Comment: @Ainar-G gccgo и gcc есть

Comment: Вам нужен компилятор си, способный производить код для Windows. Почитайте, например, вот тут: https://rakyll.org/cross-compilation/.

Comment: @ainar-g Поставил x86_64-mingw-w64, обновил CC и CXX

Comment: @ainar-g  Нет, GOTOOLDIR я не трогал, нужно поменять?

Comment: Не уверен. Расскажите, как ставили го, какая версия, и в какие директории. Может быть несовпадение версий.

Comment: @Ainar-G давно дело было, вроде как просто поставил 
gc-7.6.0-1
gcc-go-multilib-7.2.0-1
go-bindata-3.0.7-1
go-tools-2:1.9+2247+5d2fd3cc-1
godep-2:79-1

Comment: @ainar-g думаете попробовать переставить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение найдено: тупо не ставим gccgo из стандартного репозитория, ставим gc, go-tools и пакет gcc(как, он у вас не стоит по дефолту?), скачиваем Go1.9 с сайта, размещаем где-нибудь, прописываем переменные в .bash-profile (обязательно указать правильный бинарник go в $PATH)

Всё, рабочий Go у нас уже есть. Но под винду он по-прежнему не собирает. Окей

Ставим mingw-w64-(gcc+headers+crt+binutils).

Теперь всё просто: чтобы собрать под Windows/amd64 создаем где-нибудь в $PATH файлик gowin64.sh следующего содержания:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
export CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
export GOOS=windows
export GOARCH=amd64
export CGO_ENABLED=1

go build -i -o ${1%.*}_${GOOS}_${GOARCH}.exe $1
```

Всё, теперь запускаем и передаем ему в качестве параметра имя файла *.go

Answer (score 0):

```
env GOOS=windows  GOARCH=amd64 go build main.go
```

скомпилирует main.exe под x64 разрядную систему Windows.

rtfm rulezz.

Comment: неправда ваша, я же сказал - так это не работает

Comment: всё отлично работает !