# Компиляция из ubuntu на windows

Tags: golang

Когда выполняю:

```
go build main.go
```

компиляция проходит успешно и я получаю бинарный файл.

А когда я выполняю:

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o main.exe
```

получаю ошибку:

> ```
> build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/tux/go/src/github.com/gotk3/gotk3/pango
> ```

есть спсоб сборки с помощью файла .sh следующего содержания

```
export CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
export CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
export GOOS=windows
export GOARCH=amd64
export CGO_ENABLED=1
go build -i -o ${1%.*}_${GOOS}_${GOARCH}.exe $1
```

Но опять я получаю ошибку сборки:

> cc1: error: '-fsplit-stack' currently only supported on GNU/Linux
>   cc1: error: '-fsplit-stack' is not supported by this compiler configuration

как компилировать правильно под windows?

Comment: Там не совсем понятно что нужно сделать.

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725525/20161

Comment: Делаю этим способом получаю новую ошибку.